# Помогите оптимизировать код [python]

Tags: python

```py
s = []
for z in range(int(input())):
    x = input()
    if x == '-':
        print(s.pop())
    else:
        i = int(x[1:])
        x = x[0]
        if x == '+':
            s.append(i)
        else:
           print(sum(s[-i:]))
```

Смысл кода: У нас есть база данных. Мы можем:

- положить числовое значение (+x)
- удалить последнее значение (-)
- получить сумму последних k значений (?k)

Код рабочий, но долгий на больших значениях. Поможете?

P.s. В первой строке вводных данных вводиться кол-во операций. Есть гарантия, что нет операции удалить, когда база пустая, и k всегда меньше или равно кол-ву значений в базе.

Comment: Храните не сами значения (a, b, c), а суммы всех чисел до этого значения (a, a+b, a+b+c). Когда нужно будет найти сумму последних чисел, вам нужно будет от последнего числа отнять элемент массива с нужным индексом.

Comment: Да, @trollingchar, мне этого как раз хватило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
s = []
a = [0]
for z in range(int(input())):
    x = input()
    if x == '-':
        print(s.pop())
        a.pop()
    else:
        i = int(x[1:])
        x = x[0]
        if x == '+':
            s.append(i)
            a.append(i + a[-1])
        else:
            print(a[-1] - a[-1-i])
```

Это немного изменённый код. Для получения суммы последних значений заводиться ещё массив.
Спасибо за комментарий к вопросу.